# Applying white and dark style for individual TextViews through XML

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

I have a white and dark style from which the user can choose from. I already successfully applied a *cardStyle* for several *cardviews*.

Now my question is, can this be done the same way for individual TextViews? Basically I want to set *txtBgStyle* (white and dark style) for some TextViews through their .xml like this.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTb1Head"
        style="@style/txtBgStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
```

**Edit:** It should work like the cardStyle which I applied through .xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/card_view3"
            style="?attr/cardStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view2"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">
```

**Edit 2:** I am an idiot, instead of `style="?attr/txtBgStyle"` i set `style="@style/txtBgStyle"` in the textView xml.

Here is the (correct working) styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- reference to CardView White/Dark styles -->
    <attr name="cardStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="txtBgStyle" format="reference" />

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
        <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dark application theme. -->
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#232424</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B1C1C</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FAFAFA</item>
        <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/cardStyle</item>
        <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/txtBgStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- v7.widget.CardView dark style -->
    <style name="cardStyle">
        <!-- Card background color -->
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#282929</item>
    </style>

    <style name="txtBgStyle">
        <item name="android:background">#282929</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Off course it can be done. Are you getting any error while doing it?

Comment: @drWisdom, I do not know how to apply txtBgStyle for the txtView(s), setting the dark style is no problem but what about the white theme? I am quit new to styles.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the style of a textview programatically when a user selects a particular option?

Comment: I want to avoid to set it programmaticaly and choose the (easy) way through xml. Just like I did for the "cardStyle" in the styles.xml. If i change themes the cardviews nicely change from color.

Comment: @drWisdom, apologies, it works, see edit2. My mistake. Thx for your time anyhow.

Comment: @drWisdom, I have a little question related to this, I want to set a color in styles.xml defined in colors.xml like this "<item name="txtBgStyle">@color/custom_white</item>" but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: it is because txtBGStyle is a style element , you can not apply color value to a style element.

Comment: OK, clear, so I cannot set a (custom) color to it, also not directly.

Comment: set the color to android:Background attribute in your txtBGStyle style.

Comment: Already have this for the dark theme, kindly look at my styles.xml or do you mean something else? My problem is to set it for the white theme, i am looking for a way to set a (custom) white color in the white theme for txtBGStyle.